# Server-side rendering using react-router 4, how to render client version?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-router-v4

I'm learning developing react.js server-side rendering web app, I'm using Express.js and Swig for the server-side

#### Code

*server.js*

```
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path'

import React from 'react'
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import setupSwig from 'setup.swig'
import { setupStore } from '../shared/redux/store'
import { ajaxFunction } from '../shared/services/Customer'

import App from '../shared/components/App'

const app = express()
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '_public')))
setupSwig(app)

app.use((req, res) => {
    const url = req.url

    ajaxFunction()
        .then(({ data: customers }) => {
            const context = {}
            const store = setupStore({
                customers
            })

            const html = renderToString(
                <Provider store={ store }>
                    <StaticRouter location={ url } context={ context }>
                        <App />
                    </StaticRouter>
                </Provider>
            )

            const initState = store.getState()

            res.render('./index.swig', { html, initState })
        })
    }
})

app.listen(3000)
```

*client.js*

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import { setupStore } from '../shared/redux/store'
import App from '../shared/components/App'

const initState = window.__INIT_STATE__
delete window.__INIT_STATE__

const store = setupStore(initState)

render(<Provider store={ store }>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('reactApp'))
```

#### Question

On the *server.js* I use `<StaticRouter location={ url } context={ context }>` but I have no ideas how to make ((what `props` to pass with) the `<BrowserRouter>` on *client.js* redirect to specific URL e.g. `/customers`, `/about`

If I did things wrong way please also guide

Thanks